# Incompleteness of Herbrand/Functional-logic

Tags: logic, incompleteness

> The following is an excerpt from the course CS-157, Introduction to Logic, [Lesson 12.2](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/lessons/lesson_12_02.html).
>
> ... that Herbrand Logic is inherently incomplete, it is not surprising that Herbrand Logic is not compact.

What does the author mean when he says that Herbrand logic is incomplete? - does it mean that any proof-system on Herbrand logic will be incomplete.

Comment: See [Herbrand Semantics](http://logic.stanford.edu/herbrand/herbrand.html): "Herbrand semantics is an alternative semantics based directly on truth assignments for ground sentences rather than interpretations of constants. Herbrand semantics is simpler and more intuitive than Tarskian semantics.The downside is a loss of some common logical properties, such as compactness and completeness."

Comment: Thus, IMO, the issue is: the predicate logic proof system is complete wrt so-called "Tarskian semantics" while it is not so wrt "Herbrand semantics".

Comment: If so, it is not about "Incompleteness" as described in the tag definition: "Questions about Gödel's incompleteness theorems and related topics."

Comment: See also [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67547/is-herbrand-semantics-a-kind-of-term-formalism) and see Timothy Hinrichs & Michael Genesereth, [Herbrand Logic (2009)](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~hinrichs/papers/hinrichs2006herbrand.pdf)

Comment: "..., we can establish logical entailment in Herbrand Logic by writing proofs. In fact, it is possible to show that, with a few simple restrictions, a set of premises logically entails a conclusions if and only if there is a finite proof of the conclusion from the premises, even when the Herbrand base is infinite. Moreover, it is possible to find such proofs in a finite time. That said, things are not perfect. ... , if we remove the restrictions mentioned above, we lose the guarantee of finite proofs." ([source](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/lessons/lesson_12_01.html))

Comment: The author's comments about incompleteness of Herbrand logic are based on the above mentioned paragraph. This is what made me think that "any proof-system on Herbrand-logic will be incomplete". (but again, I'm not sure!)

Comment: For Herbrand logic most times when we want to prove some universally quantified sentence "we lose the guarantee of finite proofs" as your reference mentioned " a few simple restrictions, a set of premises logically entails a conclusions if and only if there is a *finite* proof of the conclusion from the premises, even when the Herbrand base is infinite". So only under these restricted cases this logic is both sound and complete like FOL, if such restrictions are removed, then it's prone to be incomplete (while still sound obviously) relative to FOL with Tarski semantics.